# ldd command is not displaying the librariers linked

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ldd

I am creating an .so file using the following commands:

For creating .o file

```
 g++ -c -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/home/user/Desktop/AutoTest/SDKTestSuite/  -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. SDKTestSuite.cpp
```

For Creating the .so file

```
 g++  -shared -o SDKTestSuite.so SDKTestSuite.o -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lpython2.7 -lDijSDK -leventflag  -lQtGui -lQtCore -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/cameras/ -lsynthcam -luusb
```

Here after creating the .so file, If I display the dependencies for the .so file using the ldd command gives the following output

```
user@emb-ubu-085:~/Desktop/AutoTest/SDKTestSuite$ ldd SDKTestSuite.so
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7792000)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0xb746c000)
libDijSDK.so.1 => /home/user/Desktop/AutoTest/SDKTestSuite/libDijSDK.so.1 (0xb6f72000)
libeventflag.so => /home/user/Desktop/AutoTest/SDKTestSuite/libeventflag.so (0xb6f6e000)
libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0xb649d000)
libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0xb61b5000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb60cc000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb60af000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb5efb000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb5ee2000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb5ec7000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb5ec2000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0xb5ebe000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb5e7a000)
libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0xb5e69000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xb5e30000)
libaudio.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2 (0xb5e17000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb5d16000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xb5cec000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xb5c51000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb5c01000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0xb5bf8000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0xb5bde000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0xb5bcd000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xb5bc3000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xb5bb1000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xb5a7a000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb5a71000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7793000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xb5a48000)
libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0xb59ec000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xb59e8000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb59a7000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xb59a0000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xb5999000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xb5977000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb5970000)
```

The issue is, I am including the libraries files libsynthcam.so and libuusb.so file while creating the SDKTestSuite.so file. And why those camera names are not displaying in the output of the ldd command.

How to make the ldd command to display those library files ?